# Autocompletion ":export" variables in ts

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, css-modules

I have ran into the issue that I do not get any autocompletions for the variables I define in :export tag.

Eg

```
// colors.module.scss
:export{
  primary: #33ee22
}
```

I can use this in my ts files like this

```
// Component.tsx

import styles from "./colros.module.scss";

console.log(styles.primary); // Output: #33ee22
```

but I do not get any suggestion when typing "styles".

I have not been able to figure out whether it's a problem with scss intellisense, or some ts configurations that needs to be done? Or do I have to manually create a type? I only have a oneliner in my custom.d.ts.

```
//custom.d.ts
declare module "*.scss";
```

Works well work classnames, eg if I add the class ".myClass" typing styles. will give me "myClass" as suggestion.

I have scss intellisense and SCSS Everywhere installed in vs code.